# SELECT/COUNT on 2 tabs, how to result just one tab?

Tags: sql, select, count, sum

Here is my like table with 6 tabs (don't if tab is the right name) I have a good request to select topics with the more likes, recents, and in a specific forum.

http://trotirider.com/stak1.jpg

```
SELECT tid, Sum(value) AS value_total
FROM punlike
WHERE value = 1
  AND (fid = 31 OR fid = 33)
GROUP BY tid
ORDER BY value_total DESC, tid DESC
```

http://trotirider.com/stak2.jpg

But I only need 'tid', value_total is just here to order by. How to get only one tab with this request ? Is it possible to make it with a sql request or do I must make it in php with a loop or other ?

Thanks.

Comment: And what's the problem with getting value_total too? You can just ignore it in your resultset, if you don't need the value. Could you describe how you're using this query?

Comment: yeah that's right... you put me on the way, I can extract the tid like this:

Comment: $resultv1 = $db->query('SELECT tid, Sum(value) AS value_total FROM punlike WHERE value = 1 AND (fid = 31 OR fid = 33) GROUP BY tid ORDER BY value_total DESC, tid DESC');

while($resultv1r = $db->fetch_assoc($resultv1))
echo $resultv1r['tid'];

Comment: in fact I need this topic id to show the topic list I want, in this case I want to show the most recent liked topics.

Comment: But I prefer to use only sql if I can (in the same time I learn new functions) I tried a select in the first select and others it didn't work, maybe you know a tip ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is going to work, but give it a shot:

```
SELECT tid
FROM punlike
WHERE value = 1
  AND fid IN (31, 33)
GROUP BY tid
ORDER BY SUM(value) DESC, tid DESC;
```

If that doesn't work, try this:

```
SELECT tid
FROM (SELECT tid, SUM(value) AS value_total
      FROM punlike
      WHERE value = 1
        AND fid IN (31, 33)
      GROUP BY tid
      ORDER BY value_total DESC, tid DESC);
```

Comment: yeah the first one seems to work fine, I have the same result but only tid just like I would.
the tip was just the sum(value) in the order, nice, I really thank you.